# $|\langle x_1,y_1\rangle -\langle x_2,y_2\rangle|\leq\|y_1\|\|x_1-x_2\|+\|x_2\|\|y_1-y_2\|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Let $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I need to prove that
$$
|\langle x_1,y_1\rangle -\langle x_2,y_2\rangle|\leq\|y_1\| \|x_1-x_2\|+\|x_2\|\|y_1-y_2\|
$$
I know the triangle inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and I guess I have to use them, but I can't figure out where to start. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Use `$\langle` to make the angled brackets, rather than `<` which makes an inequality sign. $\langle x, y\rangle$ looks much nicer than $<x,y>$! :)

Comment: See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/496937/305862).

Comment: add and substract $\langle x_2,y_1\rangle $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that
$$
\langle x_1,y_1\rangle -\langle x_2,y_2\rangle = \langle x_1-x_2,y_1\rangle +\langle x_2,y_1-y_2\rangle
$$
and then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.